Does Hogwarts Legacy have Wizard's Chess and where can I find it?
We saw Wizard's Chess in the Harry Potter films and Harry Potter videogames, but what about Hogwarts Legacy?
I'd love to play a game of Wizard's Chess against other students.
Is this available in Hogwarts Legacy? If yes, then where can I find it?

Besides some chess puzzles, there isn't any way to play a complete match of Wizard's Chess.
Other users on Reddit asked the same, and I couldn't find any positive answer, as the most voted one states:

It's a single player RPG so there wouldn't be any multi-player options, but it would be very cool to play wizards chess


I don't mean multiplayer. I know there isn't any multiplayer. I mean against other NPC students. Like how we had in Harry Potter: Order of the Phoenix.

Yep, the second sentence "but it would be very cool to play wizards chess" means that it can't be played in general.

oh i have HBP! I wish I could of played Wizard Chess, well those games arent to expensive for WII/Xbox360...
